# Is converting Pydantic model to Dict not efficient?

Tags: python, flask, python-typing, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I had a task in which I had to convert Restaurant Schedule into human readable format. This is how my implementation looks:
My pydantic model:

```
class DayValue(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["open", "close"]
    value: int = Field(gt=0, le=86399)


class RestaurantSchedule(BaseModel):
    monday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
    tuesday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
    wednesday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
    thursday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
    friday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
    saturday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
    sunday: List[Optional[DayValue]]
```

API call:

```
@app.route('/restaurant_schedule', methods=['POST'])
@validate()
def restaurant_schedule(body: RestaurantSchedule):
    restaurant_schedule_dict = body.dict()
    transformed_scheduled = transform_schedule(restaurant_schedule_dict)
    print(transformed_scheduled)
    return
```

My logic function:

```
def transform_schedule(restaurant_schedules: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, str]:
    opening_schedule = None
    opening_day = None
    closing_week_schedule = None
    final_schedule: dict = {}
    for day in days:
        final_schedule[day] = []
        for schedule in restaurant_schedules[day]:
            if schedule['type'] == 'open':
                opening_schedule = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(schedule['value']).strftime('%-I %p')
                opening_day = day
            else:
                closing_schedule = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(schedule['value']).strftime('%-I %p')
                if opening_schedule is not None:
                    final_schedule[opening_day].append(f'{opening_schedule} - {closing_schedule}')
                else:
                    closing_week_schedule = closing_schedule

    if closing_week_schedule:
        final_schedule[days[6]].append(f'{opening_schedule} - {closing_week_schedule}')

    return final_schedule
```

So, sample input request is:

```
{
    "monday": [],
    "tuesday": [
        {
            "type": "open",
            "value": 36000
        },
        {
            "type": "close",
            "value": 64800
        }
    ],
   .....
   .....
}
```

and expected response is:

```
Monday: Closed
Tuesday: 10 AM - 6 PM
.....
.....
```

So, It works fine and stuff but I got feedback saying:

> Validated schema model is converted to dict instead of using the model itself when passing to the logic function thereby losing all the typing benefits. Also, logic function also returns dict losing all the typing benefits.

Now, I am wondering converting model to dict is bad? if yes then how can I improve my implementation to stick to best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fastapi and pydantic there is no need to use a model as entry of your route and [convert it to dict](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/).

Having a model as entry let you work with the object and not the parameters of a ditc/json

exemple of object parameters:

```py
for mon in RestaurantSchedule.monday:
    print(mon)
```

That means that you have to make all your logic in transform_schedule with a RestaurantSchedule as an entry. No conversion to dict needed.

Also, you should return another model from your route, see [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/).

Why having an entry model and an output model you may ask? Isn't it overkill?

By doing that you allow fastapi to generate a swagger that show exactly what is the output an the entry of your route. Make the work easier for your front-end dev

Also for you as the back-end dev it allow you to implement TDD very easily, have a clearer view of the data you output